# How to make a start tile reference the desktop AND modern mode of an app?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, mode, live-tile

I've made an app for the Windows desktop and also created it for the modern (metro) interface in Windows 8.1. I wanted to group them under the same start tile and have a setting that allowed the user to open the app in the chosen mode by clicking the start tile. I got this idea from Chrome, which has both modes referenced by the same tile in the start menu or the link on the taskbar. I thought that maybe when the setting was changed I would delete the current one and replace it with one that referenced the other mode, but positioning is a problem, as a new tile always appears at the far right of the start screen. How would I resize the tile correctly and how would I delete and replace a link on the taskbar? I am using VB right now, but I can write C# and C++ so feel free to post code or links to code that are written in these languages.

If you have any suggestions, please post a reply or a ask a question in the comments.

I also should note that I prefer to use native libraries only and do not like using third-party dlls.

Thanks in advance for the help.

P.S. I've already tried Google.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please post what code / solutions you've already tried, as well as what happened when you tried them,(including errors, or undesired results) this will help us better understand the problem and give you a good answer :)

Comment: As of now, I only have the code from the Microsoft Sample project for creating primary and secondary tiles: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178/sourcecode?fileId=44809&pathId=1724600329, but this does not help with the placement of a tile. I am completely clueless in terms of adding to the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!

The best way to do this is to create two registry keys referencing the two interfaces but make both the desktop and modern version not have a start tile! Then create a third app that has a tile and make it open the files, check for the active interface, and send the data to that interface with the file as a param.

Thanks for everyone's help, though :)